# Postman - Very Slow - Memory Allocation

Tags: performance, memory, postman

I'm new to postman. I have an array of 8000 URLS that i'm testing for 200s. Currently testings using the application (using the front end of it and also the console)

It seems really slow and hangs alot, The array of URLs is only 5MB and it's testing for 200's in a loop, currently takes about 30 mins.

I'm thinking it's a memory issue maybe, is there anyway to check or increase the memory allocation for postman?

Thanks!

Comment: * also the console* are you using Newman?

Comment: yes, I'm using newman as well as running it from the application itself.